# Place imageview with fixed footer android

Tags: android, imageview, footer

I want to place image approx full height and a fixed footer. 
I tried this code.
Image is dynamically update using from gallery

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.aaaa.com.EditView">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/footerEdit"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addBackground"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_content" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/takePhoto"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_camera"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imgview"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I want to scale image entire screen but leave footer area
Please guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are working with relative layouts, you still can manage Header and Footer (this last for you) indicating and order between the layouts.
For your main content area add:

```
android:layout_above="@id/lytFooter"
```

to be set stacked over your footer
and

```
android:layout_below="@id/lytHeader"
```

to be set stacked below your header.

For your main content area set height to match_parent.

Hope it helps.